# Find the $LDL^{T}$ factorization of $A$ when in the range of the positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, factoring

I am trying to find the $LDL^{T}$ factorization of the following matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & b \\ b & 4 \end{bmatrix}
$$
when $b$ is in the range of positive definiteness.

I have already determined that $b$ is in the range of positive definiteness when $b < 2$.  However, I don't really understand how to find the $LDL^{T}$ factorization.  I know how to do it with a matrix with all numbers, but when I applied the same strategy to this particular matrix I got a big mess when I calculated $LDL^{T}$.

The only thing I can think to do is plug in a value less than 2 and do it the way I normally do it, but I have a feeling any time I change the value for $b$ I will get a different $LDL^{T}$ factorization.

Can anyone give me any advice?

Comment: It isn't actually too hard to write the factorization in terms of $b$, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Find eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues.

Comment: Or, more simply, apply one step of the Cholesky decomposition algorithm. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky_algorithm.

Comment: Well, I will show you my process for say $b = -2$
$$
\det\left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ -2 & 4 \end{bmatrix} \right) = 8 \quad\to\quad D = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 8 \end{bmatrix}
$$
For $L^{T}$ I put it into upper triangular form and then transpose it for $L$
$$
L^{T} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \quad L =   \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and thus
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 8 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ -2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Oh jeez,
I just looked back at my calculation.  I did
$$
L^{T}DL
$$
no wonder I was getting such a crazy answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply one step of the Cholesky decomposition algorithm to get:

> $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ b & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 4-b^2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ b & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$.