# linear algebra: quadratic function minimum

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, partial-derivative

I can't get the right answer to this question I think I have a small mistake somewhere but I can't find it...

> a) for which numbers $b$ is the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & b \\ b & 9\end{bmatrix}$ positive definite?
>
> b) Factor $A = LDL^T$ when $b$ is in the range for positive definiteness
>
> c) Find the minimum value of $F = \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + 2bxy + 9y^2) - y$ for $b$ in this range
>
> d) what is the minimum if $b = 3$

My answer is as follows

a) when $-3 < b < 3$ because $a > 0 \text{ and } ac > b^2$ must be true

b)

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

c) This is where I am stuck with the wrong answer... I should check that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} = 0$ when x is in the right range (lets say x = 2)...

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} &= x + 2y \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} &= 2x + 9y - 1 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

the first one is equal to 0 at $(0, 0)$ and the second one is equal to 0 at $(\frac{1}{2}, 0) \text{ and } (0, \frac{1}{9})$ which means they don't equal 0 at the same spot??

Comment: As I interpret the question, the problems b) and c) should be solved for *all* $b$ in the range (otherwise taking $b=0$ makes it trivial). See the [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195729/find-the-ldlt-factorization-of-a-when-in-the-range-of-the-positive-defini)

Comment: $x+2y = 0 \Rightarrow x = -2y$ and $2x+9y-1=2(-2y)+9y-1=5y-1=0\Rightarrow y=1/5$ and $x=-2/5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c) You need to find the partial derivatives parametrically:
$$F_x=\left(\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + 2bxy + 9y^2) - y\right)'_x=x+by=0 \Rightarrow x=-by;\\
F_y=\left(\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + 2bxy + 9y^2) - y\right)'_y=bx+9y-1=0 \Rightarrow -b^2y+9y-1=0 \Rightarrow \\
y=\frac1{9-b^2}, x=\frac{b}{b^2-9}\\
$$
The second order test:
$$F_{xx}=1>0,F_{yy}=9>0,F_{xy}=b,\\
\Delta=F_{xx}F_{yy}-F_{xy}^2=9-b^2>0 \ \ \text{for minimum, which is the range of $b$ from a)}$$
d) if $b=3$, there is no stationary point as the system of equations $F_x=0,F_y=0$ does not have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The partial derivatives (as computed by you) are zero when $x=-\frac 2 5$ and $y =\frac 1 5$. [ Write $x=-2y$ from the first equation and plug this into the second equation . This will give you the value of $y$. You get $x$ from $x =-2y$].

EDIT: your computation of the partial derivatives (when $b=3$) is also wrong. For example, the derivative w.r.t. $x$ is $x+3y$. I will let you make these changes and then solve for $x$ and $y$.